# Text/font spacing in TextLayer

Tags: text, fonts, spacing, pebble-sdk

I started to write my own watch face. I have problem with font spacing. I'm using custom .ttf font and my problem is that "1" and "9" digit does not have same width. When hour/minute changes from 1 to something different, whole text move. I don't know what to do with it.

I have 3 ideas to handle this problem :
- use png images of digits instead of font (more space needed, harder)
- take every digit as a single TextLayer (to display "00:00" I would need 4 TextLayers)
- some function build-in already - tried to find but without luck

I'm writing it in C.

Thanks, 
Peter.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded some other watch faces and tried to play with them. Problem was with font, not my app. I used "FontForge" to modify width of "1" in font I want to use. Now everything is working fine without splitting etc..

Comment: Glad you figured it out Peter, sorry I didn't get to this sooner!!